# How to Add UserControl Conditionally to Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I want to know how to Add a UserControl Conditionally to a Repeater Control. I have tried to add it to the placeholder which is in Repeater Control but unable to load the usercontrol. This following code doesn't work.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>  
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

 public void GetStatus(int i)
    {
        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        if(i==1)
        {
            uc = LoadControl("DraftList.ascx") as UserControl;
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
             uc = LoadControl("FinalList.ascx") as UserControl;
        }


        PlaceHolder p1 = (PlaceHolder)ResultsRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
        p1.Controls.Add(uc);

    }
```

Comment: How is not working ? It throws exception, don't load UC or something else ?

Comment: Why is it poor question i am trying to do this n have problem so i posted! if u dont know then plz leave it!

Comment: thanks Antonio Bakula for reply ! i want to bind the repeater depending on database value. Is their any alternative?

Comment: When do you call this function? Have you tried to debug it though to see if the method is called? Try to use itemdatabound event.

Comment: @SHEKHAR you should make an effort if you want answers to your question, for example I asked you how is it not working, and you answer with another question. If you leave it as it is probably there will be no answers, and attitude doesn't help either

Comment: I am Really Sorry Antonio Bakula!next time i will take care...! When i am trying to load, it shows unbinded repeater control!The Repeater Control Remains Blank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there some reason that you don't want to just handle all of this in the aspx?  That would be the simplest and cleanest option:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ResultsRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:DraftList ID="DraftList1" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((int)Eval("Status") == 1)%>' />
        <uc2:FinalList ID="FinalList1" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((int)Eval("Status") == 2)%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

If a control is not visible, (i.e., `Visible=false`) then no markup is rendered, so coding in this fashion would not create any more work for the server or the client browser, while having the benefit of being much easier to read and providing user control properties at design-time.

You would just need to make sure to register your controls at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Register src="DraftList.ascx" tagname="DraftList" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="FinalList.ascx" tagname="FinalList" tagprefix="uc2" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try adding it within the repeaters ItemDataBound event? I.e.,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" OnItemDataBound="ResultsRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>  
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void ResultsRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel PlaceHolder1 = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");

            // declare/obtain the value of i given the DataItem
            // e.g.,
            int i = ((int)e.Item.DataItem); // or however you're getting i

            if (i == 1)
            {
                var uc = LoadControl("~/DraftList.ascx");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                var uc = LoadControl("~/FinalList.ascx");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Judging by your last comment (to the question) you might need to also make sure you've attached and bound your datasource to the repeater as well. I.e.,

```
ResultsRepeater.DataSource = dataSource; //whatever your datasource is e.g., datatable, IEnumerable list etc
ResultsRepeater.DataBind();
```